# From snake_case to camelCase in Java

Tags: java, string

Can anyone tell me how to convert a string in snake_case as:

```
camel_case
```

to a string in camelCase as:

```
camelCase
```

in Java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having problems with code you've written or are we to undertake the entire task for you?

Comment: Read the doc! This is a simple problem any programming language should be able to do. I'm not familiar with Java but here is the pseudocode you might want to run by:
1. Loop through all characters in the string
2. If "_" is found, remove it
3. Capitalize the next character
4. Return the new string

Comment: You can split the string with _ and then use StringUtils.join after capitalizing the first char of all (except first) splitted string parts

Answer (score 32):

Also Guava's [CaseFormat](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat) offers quite a neat solution that allows you to transform from and to camel case and even other specific cases.

```
CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, "camel_case"); // returns camelCase
CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, "CAMEL_CASE"); // returns CamelCase
CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE, "camelCase"); // returns CAMEL_CASE
CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN, "CamelCase"); // returns camel-case
```

Comment: `CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, "camelCase");` will return "camelcase", this may not be expected

Comment: Why not? `LOWER_UNDERSCORE` would be a format like `camel_case`, i. e. only an underscore character breaks a word. The string `"camelCase"` is in this sense only one word and if you consequentially convert a one word string to `LOWER_CAMEL`, you will get everything in lower case.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`toCamelCase`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/CaseUtils.html#toCamelCase(java.lang.String,boolean,char...)) util:

```
CaseUtils.toCamelCase("camel_case", false, new char[]{'_'}); // returns "camelCase"
```

from [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/CaseUtils.html#toCamelCase(java.lang.String,boolean,char...)).

Answer (score 8):

This might be pretty, and it works

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "always_use_camel_back_notation_in_java";
        while(phrase.contains("_")) {
                phrase = phrase.replaceFirst("_[a-z]", String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(phrase.charAt(phrase.indexOf("_") + 1))));
            }
            System.out.println(phrase);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `Character.toUpper` is not a method and the second parameter to `String.replace` needs to be a String. I think you meant `replaceAll`? But even then, calling `indexOf("_")` will always return the first `_` because the underscores aren't iteratively replaced

Comment: My apologies. I was on another system without Eclipse. Now check my updated and verified answer.

Comment: It only works for phrases with one or no underscores such as "camel_case". It still will not work for "camel_case_test". That will return "camelCaseCest" since `indexOf("_")` returns the underscore before "case".

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Now it will convert any length string to camel back notation. The while loop takes care of it.

Comment: Yup. Works now. However, (I know it isn't a concern here), the runtime complexity is high with this approach.

Comment: This may loop forever if the string contains things like `permit_2pc`. Might be better to modify it with `phrase.charAt(pos = (phrase.indexOf("_", pos) + 1))` (And likewise adjust the loop condition to `s.substring(pos).contains("_")` or similar - I haven't tested this)

Answer (score 7):

## Java SE 8+

Using [Java-8 Stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html), we can do it in a single statement.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "snake_case_to_camel_case";

        str = str.indexOf("_") != -1
                ? str.substring(0, str.indexOf("_")) + 
                    Arrays.stream(str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1).split("_"))
                        .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1)).collect(Collectors.joining())
                : str;

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
snakeCaseToCamelCase
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zXu0gN)

## Java SE 9+

[`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult, String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) introduced with Java SE 9, makes it further easy.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "snake_case_to_camel_case";

        str = Pattern.compile("_([a-z])")
                    .matcher(str)
                    .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1).toUpperCase());

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
snakeCaseToCamelCase
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YmquyW)

Answer (score 6):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

```
String phrase = "camel_case";
String[] words = phrase.split("_");
String newPhrase = words[0];
for(int i=1; i<words.length; i++){
  newPhrase += words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at oracle's documentation for the [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, notably [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)), and [toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())

(You can use these as puzzle pieces to solve your problem)

Comment: I would just use `split` and `Character.toUpperCase`. Not sure where `substring` comes into play

Comment: @cricket_007 that should work too, I wasn't aware of `split`, but I'm not very familiar with regex either

Comment: Don't need regex, you can simply split on underscore

Answer (score 3):

Using `split("_")` and looping over those parts is one way to do it.

Here is an alternative using a `StringBuilder`.

```
String s = "make_me_camel_case";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '_') {
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        sb.replace(i, i+1, String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i))));
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString()); // makeMeCamelCase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public String snakeToCamelCase(String snakeWord) {
    String camelWord = snakeWord.replaceAll("_", " ");
    camelWord = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(camelWord);
    return camelWord.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by providing more information on how it works and what's required such as used libraries. `WordUtils` is part of an external library.

Comment: import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils` is deprecated as of 3.6

Comment: @FrederikClaus what is the alternative if its deprecated?

Comment: @ennth WordUtils from commons-text: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html

The project I worked on had no dependency on commons-text and therefore I went with the Java 9+ solution by Arvind Kumar Avinash

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Converts AlphaNumeric String to camelcase based on any non AlphaNumeric char as delimiter
 * @param input
 * @return camelCase String
 */
public static String toCamelCase(String input) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    boolean toUpper = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(input.charAt(i))) {

            if (toUpper) {

                result.append(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
                toUpper = false;
            } else {

                result.append(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
            }
        } else if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))){

            result.append(input.charAt(i));
        } else {

            toUpper = true;
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

@Test
public void toCamelCaseTest() {

    List<String> inputs = List.of("Hello World", "helloWorld",
            "Hello_World", "helloWorld",
            "Hello-World", "helloWorld",
            "HELLO WORLD", "helloWorld",
            "HELlo_WORld", "helloWorld",
            "Hello1world", "hello1world",
            "2Hello world", "2helloWorld"
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size();) {
        Truth.assertThat(StringUtils.toCamelCase(inputs.get(i++)))
                .isEqualTo(inputs.get(i++));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be done with the `String.split` method, and a for-loop.

```java
String convert(String string) {
    String[] strings = string.split("_+");
    StringBuilder converted = new StringBuilder();
    String stringA, stringB;
    for (String value : strings) {
        if (converted.isEmpty()) {
            if (!value.isEmpty()) converted.append(value.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            stringA = value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            stringB = value.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            converted.append(stringA).append(stringB);
        }
    }
    return converted.toString();
}
```

Input

```
convert_snake_case_to_camel_case
```

Output

```
convertSnakeCaseToCamelCase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String snakeToCamel(String input) {
        if (!input.contains("_")){
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input");
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] words = input.split("_");
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < words[j].length(); i++) {
                char letter = words[j].charAt(i);
                if (j != 0 && i == 0) {
                    sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(letter));
                } else {
                    sb.append(letter);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```