# Conversion of initial character to uppercase in java

Tags: java

how to convert a starting character of each string into capital letter.
example:

---

input:time to think

---

Output:Time To Think

Comment: give me the quick one

Comment: I answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228942/from-camel-case-to-camelcase-in-java/34229081#34229081) recently and its quite a similar problem, take a look and let me know if you still need help with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String capitalizeString(String string) {
  char[] chars = string.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
  boolean found = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (!found && Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
      chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
      found = true;
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(chars[i]) || chars[i]=='.' || chars[i]=='\'') { // You can add other chars here
      found = false;
    }
  }
  return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

**WordUtils.capitalize(str) (from apache commons-lang)**

(Note: if you need "fOO BAr" to become "Foo Bar", then use capitalizeFully(..) instead)

or you can also do it as,

```
         String str="hello how are you".trim();
         String[] arr = str.split(" ");
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0)))
                 .append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
         }

         System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`WordUtils.capitalize(str)` in apache commons should do the trick http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)