# Convert kebab-case to camelCase

Tags: java, camelcasing, kebab-case

I'm looking for a simple return inside a method that converts any use of kebab-case and turns it into camelCase.

For example:

```
hello-world
```

Becomes

```
helloWorld
```

I'm trying to use `.replaceAll()` but I can't seem to get it right!

Comment: ***String#replaceAll*** doesn't let us generate dynamically replacement based on what was found, like for `a` generate `A`. But ***Matcher#replaceAll*** has overloaded version which accepts `Function<MatchResult, String> replacer`. We can use it like to dynamically generate replacement based on current match. So your code can look like `String replaced = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-z])-([a-z])").matcher(text).replaceAll(matchResult -> matchResult.group(1).toUpperCase());`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
String kebab = "hello-world";
String camel = Pattern.compile("-([a-z])")
    .matcher(kebab)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase());
```

You can also include a lookbehind of `(?<=[a-z])` before the dash as in Pshemo's comment, if you want to only do it for dashes that come after lowercase letters instead of all instances of a dash followed by a lowercase letter, but assuming your inputs are well-formed kebab-case strings, that may not be necessary. It all depends on how you would like "-hello-world" or "HI-there" or "top10-answers" to be handled.

**Note that this only works with Java 9+ with the introduction of [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult, String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-)**

Answer (score 3):

```
String kebab = "hello-world";
String camel = Pattern.compile("-(.)")
    .matcher(kebab)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase());
```

It takes the char after the hyphen and turns it to upper-case.

**Note that this only works with Java 9+ with the introduction of [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult, String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-)**

Answer (score 1):

Just find the index of the - and then put the next char toUpperCase(), then remove the (-). You need to check if have more than one (-) and also check if the string don't have a (-) at the start of the sentence because u don't want this result:

```
Wrong: -hello-world => HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily adapt [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228942/from-snake-case-to-camelcase-in-java/34230342):

```
public String toCamel(String sentence) {
    sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    String[] words = sentence.split("-");
    String camelCase= words[0];
    for(int i=1; i<words.length; i++){
        camelCase += words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
    }
    return camelCase;
}
```