# Mapping from map to bean using snake case to camel case strategy

Tags: mapstruct

I need to convert an object of `Map<String,String>` with keys like `"some_att_name"` to class object fields like `someAttName`.

I couldn't find an easy way to do this.
MapStruct does support this type of mapping (From `Map` to object) since `v1.5.0.Beta1` as stated [here](https://mapstruct.org/news/2021-07-18-mapstruct-1_5_0_Beta1-is-out/).

What I want should look something like this (similar to how JSON converters work):

```
@Mapper
public interface MapToObjectMapper {

    MapToObjectMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MapToObjectMapper.class);

    @Mapping(strategy = SnakeCaseToCamelCaseStrategy.class)
    MyObject toMyObject(Map<String,String> map);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to translate the keys by yourself, but that's not that hard. Here is how I do it:

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

@Mapper
public interface MapToObjectMapper {
    MapToObjectMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MapToObjectMapper.class);

    private static String snakeToCamel(String snakeCaseString) {
        // You can use Guava, Apache Commons, write it yourself or just use this one
        // Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67605103/4494577
        return Pattern.compile("_([a-z])")
                .matcher(snakeCaseString)
                .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }

    MyObject toMyObject(Map<String, String> map);

    default MyObject toMyObjectFromSnakeCaseMap(Map<String, String> snakeKeyPropertyMap) {
        return toMyObject(snakeKeyPropertyMap.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(collectingAndThen(
                        toMap(s -> snakeToCamel(s.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue),
                        Collections::unmodifiableMap)));
    }
}
```

Full example: https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--mapstruct-snake-case-map-mapping/

Comment: Appreciate providing the full code solution. That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs I can't see a 1 step mapping. I think referring to [From snake_case to camelCase in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228942/from-snake-case-to-camelcase-in-java) for converting your Map's keys to camelCase and then going for a mapper without `@Mapping` annotations might be your best chance.

Comment: True, I ended up converting to camelCase. It's a bit of a shame that MapStruct doesn't support strategies like JSON converters. Should be easy enough to implement.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, to play around with